# How can set disk IO priority automatically?

Tags: disk, process-priority

If I use some IO intensive application (like Virtualbox, Steam data verification or even `dd`) my system becomes almost unresponsive. Despite  all being started with normal priority, they make the desktop very sluggish and delay a lot the startup of other applications.

I know I can use something like `ionice` to change the priority to idle for instance, but in the case of Virtualbox which spawns many processes it becomes difficult.

Can I give some type of hints to the system, so when launching some specific applications they are started with the least IO priority?

Comment: did you try my solution? Does it do the job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: This solution only works with the cfq scheduler, as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160081). You should check which one is used by issuing*

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

*and [change](http://www.admon.org/system-tuning/how-to-change-default-io-scheduler/) it if necessary.*

If I understood correctly, you want some `ionice` setting to be applied every time you start a command. You can do it this way:

```
echo 'ionice -c 3 /usr/bin/VirtualBox "$@"' > VirtualBox
chmod a+x VirtualBox
sudo mv VirtualBox /usr/local/bin/
```

First command creates a file `VirtualBox` with the single-quoted text as its content. This should have the full path to the program, because if one only specify `VirtualBox` it can interpret it as the file we just created and create a "loop".

Second command makes it executable, and third moves this new file in a folder which is in front of the "system" bin folder `/usr/bin`, so our new file gets executed instead of the original. The "$@" part contains all the arguments the command was invoked with, so they get forwarded to the real VirtualBox command.

According to answer ("yes") to this Super User question [Do children processes inherit ionice priorities from their parents? How do you check the IO priority of a running process?](https://superuser.com/questions/63091/do-children-processes-inherit-ionice-priorities-from-their-parents-how-do-you-c), it should be enough to `ionice` the parent process, like this:

```
ionice -c 3 VirtualBox
```

From `ionice` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice), following I/O scheduling class values are available:

- 0 for none
- 1 for realtime
- 2 for best-effort
- 3 for idle (used in example above)

A number or class name can be used.

Also, `-n level` option is applicable for realtime and best-effort classes, with 0-7 as valid data (priority levels).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Lucio, thanks for a hint, but isn't "it should be enough to `ionice` the parent process" essential part?

Comment: Yes, your right. But, *if you can*, take a time and then add more information from your own experience about this procedure, creating a better *answer* :)

Comment: @Lucio, I hope it's good enough now. Thank you for insisting (:

Comment: @sm4rk0 Yes it works, and is pretty clean too (no modification of package/system files). I was looking for something like `limits.conf` but all alternatives I've found are much more complicated than this. Thanks

Comment: @Salem Thanks for the correction: appropriate case in `VirtualBox` and avoiding the loop situation! I'm glad to have been of help.

Comment: FYI: `ionice` can working with `cfq` scheduler only! For more details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136226/does-ionice-work-with-the-deadline-scheduler

Comment: Thanks @andras.tim! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is a great post learning ionice and the combination of basic Ubuntu commands. As to "$@", $ means the last part, but what does @ mean??

Comment: why do you do such a "ionice -c 3 VirtualBox" command?? VirtualBox has already contained ionice settings.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'renice' command to prioritise processes:

```
renice -<priority> <application's pid>
```

It could also be your drive is spinning down too much, so when you want to start application like Virtualbox it has to spin up before you can start working around (this can take a while).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i was looking for a way to make that automatically and system wide. For example: when launching Virtualbox, run it with the lowest IO priority possible...

Comment: regular nice and renice don't prioritize IO separately.

Comment: And this is nice, not ionice. The one is for CPU the other for IO.