# How to slow down moving files / file transfer? (so the target disk is not that occupied)

Tags: hard-drive, files, ssd, transfer

I am using Ubuntu 17. I am moving files from SSD (also the system disk) to a HDD. However, at the same time, I need to browse and use files from the HDD - but moving files to the HDD slows the working with it very much.

This might sound rather strange - but is there a way

**how to slow down file moving / trasnfer? ...**

*...so the HDD would not be occupied that much?*

(I understand all of the disadvantages of doing so... so I am looking really for a "how to" rather than why not... :) )

Comment: Maybe it will work if you `renice` the copy process, give it a high 'nice value' for example 15 (where 0 is standard and 19 is max), which should give other processes priority, https://askubuntu.com/questions/869195/how-to-change-niceness-while-perfoming-top-command/869201#869201 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/972138/assign-program-its-own-swap-drive/972447#972447

Comment: Possibly related: [How can set disk IO priority automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256852/how-can-set-disk-io-priority-automatically)

Comment: @sudodus Well the moving process is done through nautilus - so should I renice nautilus ?  wouldn't it affect other nautilus interaction?

Comment: Nautilus calls other programs/processes, and it might not work well to renice Nautilus. In this case maybe @steeldriver's tip is better. An alternative is to use a more direct tool for the copying: `cp` or `rsync`, and this might work better with `renice`.